# Method to return data from different ranges using the same function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a method to use the same function from a script to return multiple different data ranges for output to another sheet within Google Sheets.

This is my first attempt at using Google scripts for any automation, so bear with me. This project is designed as a system to place a product order from an inventory sheet. The inventory sheet contains product information and part numbers which are used in the ordering process. I created a script with a button trigger which copies the data from one sheet to an order sheet, which can later be printed off. This allows another staff member to have all information needed to place the order. The problem is that I am only able to copy one product to the order sheet with each script, is there another way to do this?

**Product Inventory (copied from)**

[image]

**Order Form (copied to)**

[image]

The first image is where the data would be copied from and it would be added to the sheet shown in the second. I want to be able to use another button running the same script as the first to copy the second row of information to the order sheet. (The quantity row is filled in by the user and will also get copied to the order)

This is the button script:

```
  //Copies Part Info
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1])// Sets the active sheet to the complete inventory
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:D2')// This is the one that I am able to copy
  var values = range.getValues()// Stores the product info
  return values;
  //Pastes Info to Order
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0])// Sets the order sheet as active
  var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow()//The next few lines find the next empty row on the sheet to paste the next data into
  var nextRow = parseInt(lastRow)+1
  var reqRange = activeSheet.getRange("A1:D100")
  var inputCell = reqRange.getCell(nextRow,1)
  var addData = inputCell.setValue(values)//Pastes the part info into the availabe cell
```

Is there a way to use the same script on multiple products or will a copy have to be made for each?

Comment: In general, I say probably. But if you can share some of your spreadsheet and explain your needs a little more precisely we can make a better determination of the problem.

Comment: I updated my post with some images and a little more information. Hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using a dialog to order parts from Inventory Sheet

Obviously, this will be a lot more complicated in real life but this is just a sample to get you started.  You will probably want to insure that the active page is an order and possibly has today's date and then you probably want to pick a quanity and subtract that from the inventory.  So things can get more complicated fairly quickly.

If this were a job I was doing for a client I would actually use a templated html approach you can read about that in the reference below.

```
function onOpen() {//Drop Down Menu You will need to run this from the editor to get it to create a menu.  Or close and then open the spreadsheet.  If you have other menus then make sure you put this in another project.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Order Parts')
  .addItem('Show Order Dialog', 'getInventory')
  .addToUi();
}

function getInventory() {//show order dialog for selecting parts
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Inventory');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var pA=rg.getValues();
  var html="<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td></tr>','Brand','Product Description','Item','Quantity')
  for(var i=0;i<pA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="button" value="Order" onClick="moveToOrder(%s);" /></td></tr>',pA[i][0],pA[i][2],pA[i][2],pA[i][3],i+2)
  }
  html+='</table><br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  html+='<script>function moveToOrder(row){google.script.run.moveToOrder(row);};console.log("MyCode");</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(600).setHeight(300).setTitle('Inventory');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface,'Inventory');
}

function moveToOrder(row) { //moves selected part to active page so make sure your on the right order form
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Inventory');
  var rg=sh.getRange(row,1,1,3);
  var pA=rg.getValues();
  var osh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  osh.appendRow(pA[0]);
}
```

My inventory sheet:

[image]

My Order Form:

[image]

Click on Show Order Dialog in Menu and dialog appears

[image]

The click button next to part that you wish to order and part appears on order

[image]

[Templated Html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

[Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/)

Comment: I applied these methods to my own sheet and it works great. Thank you! I have one more question though, is it possible to add script so that you can adjust the quantity values from within the order dialog. The second sheet is not so much of an inventory as just a list of products that can be ordered, so the quantity is just how much needs to be ordered. I adjusted the script to add that number to the order but it would be great if the number could be changed from the dialog. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. But it's not easy to do the way that I showed you because I have to write the script as text.  It would be better to do it as templated html solution so that the scripts are easier to read and to write.  I can put together an example together for you.  And I'll post it may be tomorrow.  May be I'll ask to ask another question so it won't make the page too complicated.

Comment: I will look into doing it with the templated html and try to figure it out. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing the templated html right now, which I think will work

Comment: Your welcome to take a copy if you want to refer to it. I also added the inventory quantity update back to the dialog and also turned the background red if below zero.

Comment: I like this script except I want to change it so that there is not a quantity that will be subtracted from. I just want it to be the number that will get added to the order and not be have a quantity that it takes from. I have tried to edit it but I am unable to get it to apply to the order form after changing the format. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure where in the script your speaking about perhaps you could ask it as another question and post the area of the code that your referring to.

Comment: I posted a new question